# Unique search box and buttons for tables on page

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I'm using VueJS3 to render n-tables on a singular page and have implemented table pagination in the backend using TypeORMs `skip()` and `take()` methods.

In order to provide the api with the page number and the number of rows to display on that page I created a drop down select to decide how many items to show on the page and a set of buttons to navigate the pages. I have also added a search bar to search the table.

The way I record whether or not a "pagination" selection is made is by adding an `eventListener` to the drop down list and the set of buttons - this works perfectly fine when there is a single table on the page (including the table searching) but when I get to more than one table on the page the second table doesn't respond to the page numbers changing (via the buttons rendered for it) and the for the search bars, adding text in one text box populates all text boxes.

Here is the code for the table rendering:

```
<div v-for="(table, index) in this.Tables">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-35">
            <input v-bind:id="'tableSearch' + table.id" v-model="searchText" type="text" placeholder="Search..." class="searchBar"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-25">
            <div class="options">
                <label>Show&#160;&#160;</label>
                    <select style="border-radius: 10px;" v-bind:id="'tableOptions' + table.id" @change="this.getLimit($event)">
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                        <option value="15">15</option>
                        <option value="20">20</option>
                        <option value="50">50</option>
                        <option value="70">70</option>
                        <option value="100">100</option>

                    </select>
                    <label >&#160;&#160;entries</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-35">
                <div v-bind:id="'tablePage' + table.id" class="pagination">
                    <button class="btn pg-btn">&laquo;</button>
                    <button class="btn pg-btn active">1</button>
                    <button class="btn pg-btn">2</button>
                    <button class="btn pg-btn">3</button>
                    <button class="btn pg-btn">4</button>
                    <button class="btn pg-btn">5</button>
                    <button class="btn pg-btn">6</button>
                    <button class="btn pg-btn">&raquo;</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
                
        <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
            <table class="table table-hover bdr" v-bind:id="'workflowTable' + table.id">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th v-for="{header, id} in this.headers" v-bind:id="id" :key="id">
                            {{header}}
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr v-for="row in this.filteredRows">
                        <td v-for="header in this.headers" v-bind:name="header.header" v-bind:id="row.id">{{ row[header.header] }}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the function `this.getLimit()` which sends how many items to show to the API:

```
getLimit(event){
    this.limit = event.target.value
    this.paginate(this.limit, this.page)
}
```

Finally, to check whether or not a buttons has been clicked (to navigate the pages of the table) I added the following code to the `mounted` lifecycle function:

```
var self = this;
var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("pg-btn")

for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    btns[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
        var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
        current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "")
        this.className += " active";
        self.paginate(self.limit, this.innerHTML)
    })
}
```

I'm not even sure if this is the right way to implement such a feature (I could have used DataTables but I wanted to avoid JQuery and/or VueJS datatables only because I wanted all the pagination to take place in the backend).

Any help/advice on how to get this to work for n-tables would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put your table into a separate component. Also you shouldn't use DOM, use only Vue features.

Also this:

```
                    <button class="btn pg-btn">&laquo;</button>
                    <button class="btn pg-btn active">1</button>
                    <button class="btn pg-btn">2</button>
                    <button class="btn pg-btn">3</button>
                    <button class="btn pg-btn">4</button>
                    <button class="btn pg-btn">5</button>
                    <button class="btn pg-btn">6</button>
                    <button class="btn pg-btn">&raquo;</button>
```

should be replace with `<button @click=".." v-for="..."></button>`. The same for the `<select>`.

TableComponent.vue:

```
<template>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-35">
            <input v-bind:id="'tableSearch' + table.id" v-model="searchText" type="text" placeholder="Search..." class="searchBar"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-25">
            <div class="options">
                <label>Show&#160;&#160;</label>
                    <select style="border-radius: 10px;" v-bind:id="'tableOptions' + table.id" @change="this.getLimit($event)">
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                        <option value="15">15</option>
                        <option value="20">20</option>
                        <option value="50">50</option>
                        <option value="70">70</option>
                        <option value="100">100</option>

                    </select>
                    <label >&#160;&#160;entries</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-35">
                <div v-bind:id="'tablePage' + table.id" class="pagination">
                    <button class="btn pg-btn" @click="..." v-for="..."><button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
                
        <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
            <table class="table table-hover bdr" v-bind:id="'workflowTable' + table.id">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th v-for="{header, id} in this.headers" v-bind:id="id" :key="id">
                            {{header}}
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr v-for="row in this.filteredRows">
                        <td v-for="header in this.headers" v-bind:name="header.header" v-bind:id="row.id">{{ row[header.header] }}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you, I don't know why I didn't think of doing it in that way